# How to adjust menu opacity, but not the text?

Tags: css, menu

I want to change the opacity of the menu color but not the text, so this will show me the background image of my container. Here is my CSS code

```
.nav {
    font-family: 'Lato', helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    left: 580px;
    top: 42px;
    background:#1f7f5c;
    height:60px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size:16px;
    display:block;
    line-height:60px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
    padding:0 26px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', helvetica, arial;
    text-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #2ecc71;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the background color specify an alpha channel by using `rgba()`

```
.nav {
    background-color: rgba(31, 127, 92, 0.75); /* 75% opacity */
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(46, 206, 112, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but it's worth noting it's not supported in older browsers (IE8 and earlier). http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors

Comment: In that case you would have to use `ms-filter` for older versions of IE.

Comment: @Bobby - Thanks, it's working. Can you tell me how can i write the ms-filter, i don't know about the ms-filter.

Answer (score 0):

On the background Tag use RGBA methode and specify the opacity. If you use opacity property it will be applied to all the child elements 
like

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

I used this on http://nationalspaceolympiad.com/ header. Check that with firebug.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply opacity to parent node then all child node will get affect surely. I suggest you instead of using opacity or alpha you can create a same color transparent image & put it as your background.